# Accessing Jenkins variable dynamically, which contains another variable substring

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-cli

I have two Jenkins job secret file variables called stage_xfile and prod_xfile.
ENV is another variable which contains the deploy environment variable stage/prod.
I want to dynamically access secret file for stage and prod in sh command like this:

```
cp ${${ENV}_xfile} db/secret/
```

I'm not able to make it work after trying different combinations. Any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You can create file name in separate variable and then use it:

```
def fileName = "${ENV}_xfile"
sh "cp ${fileName} db/secret/"
```

Comment: fileName is variable. Share your pipeline

Comment: filename is secret file variable binding in Jenkins job.